# How to write this join?

Tags: t-sql, left-join

I am struggling to write a join between two tables.  Easier to show you rather than describe it but Stackoverflow insists on more words so here we go...  I have two tables that can be LEFT JOINED on two columns.  All rows are present in Tbl1, not missing rows.  Some gaps in the data in Tbl2.  However, the column in Tbl2 that is not in Tbl1 (DBName) in this example, needs to be returned as NULL if it is missing from the join.   Like I said, easier to show you!  See below.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tbl1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tbl1
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tbl2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tbl2
go

CREATE TABLE #tbl1
(
Name varchar(8),
StartDate datetime
)
go

INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES ( 'Server1','2018-01-01 00:00:00')
INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES ( 'Server1','2018-02-01 00:00:00')
INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES ( 'Server1','2018-03-04 00:00:00')

INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES ( 'Server2','2018-01-05 00:00:00')
INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES ( 'Server2','2018-02-04 00:00:00')
INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES ( 'Server2','2018-03-10 00:00:00')
INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES ( 'Server2','2018-05-12 00:00:00')

INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES ( 'Server3','2018-01-12 00:00:00')

INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES ( 'Server4','2018-02-23 00:00:00')
GO

CREATE TABLE #tbl2
(
Name varchar(8),
StartDate datetime,
DBName varchar(8)
)
go

INSERT INTO #tbl2 VALUES ( 'Server1','2018-01-01 00:00:00', 'MyDB1')
INSERT INTO #tbl2 VALUES ( 'Server1','2018-02-01 00:00:00', 'MyDB1')
INSERT INTO #tbl2 VALUES ( 'Server1','2018-03-04 00:00:00', 'MyDB1')

INSERT INTO #tbl2 VALUES ( 'Server1','2018-01-01 00:00:00', 'MyDB2')
INSERT INTO #tbl2 VALUES ( 'Server1','2018-02-01 00:00:00', 'MyDB2')
INSERT INTO #tbl2 VALUES ( 'Server1','2018-03-04 00:00:00', 'MyDB2')

INSERT INTO #tbl2 VALUES ( 'Server1','2018-01-01 00:00:00', 'MyDB3')
--INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES ( 'Server1','2018-02-01 00:00:00', 'MyDB2')  -- let's say this is missing
INSERT INTO #tbl2 VALUES ( 'Server1','2018-03-04 00:00:00', 'MyDB3')

INSERT INTO #tbl2 VALUES ( 'Server2','2018-01-05 00:00:00', 'MyDB4')
INSERT INTO #tbl2 VALUES ( 'Server2','2018-02-04 00:00:00', 'MyDB4')
INSERT INTO #tbl2 VALUES ( 'Server2','2018-03-10 00:00:00', 'MyDB4')
INSERT INTO #tbl2 VALUES ( 'Server2','2018-05-12 00:00:00', 'MyDB4')

INSERT INTO #tbl2 VALUES ( 'Server2','2018-01-05 00:00:00', 'MyDB5')
INSERT INTO #tbl2 VALUES ( 'Server2','2018-02-04 00:00:00', 'MyDB5')
--INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES ( 'Server2','2018-03-10 00:00:00', 'MyDB5')  -- let's say this is missing
INSERT INTO #tbl2 VALUES ( 'Server2','2018-05-12 00:00:00', 'MyDB5')

INSERT INTO #tbl2 VALUES ( 'Server3','2018-01-12 00:00:00', 'MyDB6') 
GO


SELECT 
    a.*,
    b.DBName
FROM 
     #tbl1 a
     LEFT JOIN #tbl2 b
     ON a.Name = b.Name AND a.StartDate = b.StartDate
ORDER BY
    a.Name,
    b.DBName,
    a.StartDate desc
```

The above query does what you would expect with this output...

```
Name    StartDate           DBName
Server1 2018-03-04 00:00:00.000 MyDB1
Server1 2018-02-01 00:00:00.000 MyDB1
Server1 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 MyDB1
Server1 2018-03-04 00:00:00.000 MyDB2
Server1 2018-02-01 00:00:00.000 MyDB2
Server1 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 MyDB2
Server1 2018-03-04 00:00:00.000 MyDB3
Server1 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 MyDB3
Server2 2018-05-12 00:00:00.000 MyDB4
Server2 2018-03-10 00:00:00.000 MyDB4
Server2 2018-02-04 00:00:00.000 MyDB4
Server2 2018-01-05 00:00:00.000 MyDB4
Server2 2018-05-12 00:00:00.000 MyDB5
Server2 2018-02-04 00:00:00.000 MyDB5
Server2 2018-01-05 00:00:00.000 MyDB5
Server3 2018-01-12 00:00:00.000 MyDB6
Server4 2018-02-23 00:00:00.000 NULL
```

What I want is output that includes a row with a NULL value for the DBName where that row is missing in #Tbl2 ...

```
Server1 2018-03-04 00:00:00.000 MyDB1
Server1 2018-02-01 00:00:00.000 MyDB1
Server1 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 MyDB1
Server1 2018-03-04 00:00:00.000 MyDB2
Server1 2018-02-01 00:00:00.000 MyDB2
Server1 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 MyDB2
Server1 2018-03-04 00:00:00.000 MyDB3
Server1 2018-02-01 00:00:00.000 NULL     -- <<<<<<<<<<<<
Server1 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 MyDB3
Server2 2018-05-12 00:00:00.000 MyDB4
Server2 2018-03-10 00:00:00.000 MyDB4
Server2 2018-02-04 00:00:00.000 MyDB4
Server2 2018-01-05 00:00:00.000 MyDB4
Server2 2018-05-12 00:00:00.000 MyDB5
Server2 2018-02-04 00:00:00.000 MyDB5
Server2 2018-03-10 00:00:00.000 NULL     -- <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
Server2 2018-01-05 00:00:00.000 MyDB5
Server3 2018-01-12 00:00:00.000 MyDB6
Server4 2018-02-23 00:00:00.000 NULL
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me?  There is a matching row in `#tbl1` for values `Server1  |  2018-02-01 00:00:00.000` so the output is correct, because it returns that row with the correct `DBName` value of `MyDB1`...  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Your current left join, with the filtering all contained within the `ON` clause, is already correct.  Not sure there is a question here.

Comment: I would like a different query that produces the example result set at the end.   See the extra two rows in there will NULL for the dbName?

Comment: But why?  Where do the `null` values come from?  There are matching rows in `#Tbl1` for those values so a `join` of any kind will match and therefore not return a `null`...  What is the logic that you think will produce these `null`s?

Comment: I collected data in Table 2 once per day that represents potentially unused databases.   Using DMVs for this so has span SQL Server service restarts.  For example, over 6 months, there might be around 6 restarts for patching or whatever.

Comment: To be realistically 'unused', we would want to se 6 consecutive records in Table 2.    However, if a given database is used on one occasion over the period, that can only be recognised by not being in Table 2 for that period of uptime.

Comment: Therefore, as I collect all SQL Server service restarts in Table 1, I was thinking that I could join the two sets of data and show any gaps.   Yes, I could collect records in Table 2 for databases that have been used and that would be much simpler but we have too many databases to do it that way I think.  ie. A heck of a lot of data collection every day.   However, I might have to go back and reconsider that decision if there is now way to get a solution.

Comment: Please clarify by editing your post to the best presentation, not by commenting. Don't append to unclear writing, replace it. An MCVE includes not "more words" but a *clear specification & explanation*. (Any 2 tables "can be left joined". We don't know what you think we "would expect". "that row is missing" is not clear.) PS Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join.

Comment: @Clive  As philipxy states, add this additional information to your question not as comments.  Your situation and requirements is still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The only question I can think that you may be trying to ask here is that you want values in your right table to be returned even when there is no matching row in your left table?

If this is the case, you can use a combination of `full outer join` and `isnull` to return a full dataset that combines both tables into one consolidated output.  So instead of this `select`:

```
select a.Name
      ,a.StartDate
      ,b.DBName
from #tbl1 a
    left join #tbl2 b
        on a.Name = b.Name
            and a.StartDate = b.StartDate
order by a.Name
        ,b.DBName
        ,a.StartDate desc
```

Run this:

```
select isnull(a.Name,b.Name) as Name
      ,isnull(a.StartDate,b.StartDate) as StartDate
      ,case when a.Name is not null then b.DBName end as DBName
from @tbl1 a
    full outer join @tbl2 b
        on a.Name = b.Name
            and a.StartDate = b.StartDate
order by Name
        ,DBName
        ,StartDate desc
```

To get this, which is not quite aligned with your desired output but then I am fairly sure that without further information yours is impossible:

```
+---------+-------------------------+--------+
|  Name   |        StartDate        | DBName |
+---------+-------------------------+--------+
| Server1 | 2018-02-01 00:00:00.000 | NULL   |
| Server1 | 2018-02-01 00:00:00.000 | NULL   |
| Server1 | 2018-03-04 00:00:00.000 | MyDB1  |
| Server1 | 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 | MyDB1  |
| Server1 | 2018-03-04 00:00:00.000 | MyDB2  |
| Server1 | 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 | MyDB2  |
| Server1 | 2018-03-04 00:00:00.000 | MyDB3  |
| Server1 | 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 | MyDB3  |
| Server2 | 2018-03-10 00:00:00.000 | NULL   |
| Server2 | 2018-05-12 00:00:00.000 | MyDB4  |
| Server2 | 2018-02-04 00:00:00.000 | MyDB4  |
| Server2 | 2018-01-05 00:00:00.000 | MyDB4  |
| Server2 | 2018-05-12 00:00:00.000 | MyDB5  |
| Server2 | 2018-02-04 00:00:00.000 | MyDB5  |
| Server2 | 2018-01-05 00:00:00.000 | MyDB5  |
| Server3 | 2018-01-12 00:00:00.000 | MyDB6  |
| Server4 | 2018-02-23 00:00:00.000 | NULL   |
+---------+-------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you but the full outer join gives the same results as a left join.  Maybe it is impossible, don't know.

Comment: @Clive Look at my output, it is clearly different from the first one in your question.  The important distinction is the `isnull` and `case` is the `select`.  Did you actually test my script?  If so and the result is the same, you have grossly misrepresented your situation in your question.

Comment: Yes, of course I tested your script.  No I did not GROSSLY **misrepresent** my situation.   Please take care with your language.

Comment: @Clive  If that is the case, how you can state that *the full outer join gives the same results as a left join* when that is demonstrably false?  My output (full outer) is different to yours (left)?  I mean, simply count the `null` values returned in both...